# How to handle the click event on current location icon on google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting an icon shown in the figure on the google Maps. Now i have the confusion how to show the current location on the maps with marker whenever a user clicks on the current Location icon the google maps.
After placing this code i got the icon on the google maps

```
Map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

[image]

On the top-right google map is showing the current location icon, Now my confusion is how to handle this event to show my current location on the google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener()` and override

```
@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick(){
   return false;
}
```

returning false does the default behavior

Comment: I didn't got the point default behaviour. Will it will get the current location implicitly or I have to write the code to get current location data

Comment: the default behavior is to go to the current location. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener.html